# Activity sopped when should be started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I create notification from a service. This notification contains an intent that create activity **A** :

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
...
```

And activity **A**, when receives intent, create activity **B** using the same flag.

**Problem is:** When I currently show nothing (app is closed or in background), it works. When I click on notification and activity **A** is currently shown, it works too and I have this trace:

```
onActivityPaused(com.*****.A)
onActivityCreated(com..*****.A)
onActivityStarted(com..*****.A)
onActivityResumed(com..*****.A)
onActivityPaused(com..*****.A)
onActivityCreated(com..*****.B)
onActivityStarted(com..*****.B)
onActivityResumed(com..*****.B)
onActivityStopped(com..*****.A)
onActivityDestroyed(com..*****.A)
onActivityStopped(com..*****.A)
```

(Something's strange because A is stopped two times while my flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` should not re-create a new one?)

But when I currently show activity **B**, it is launched then stopped and destroyed... I don't understand why and I need this activity to just (re)start. Here the trace:

```
onActivityPaused(com.*****.B)         ? Why existing B is not destroyed ?
onActivityDestroyed(com.*****.A)
onActivityCreated(com.*****.A)
onActivityStarted(com.*****.A)
onActivityResumed(com.*****.A)
onActivityPaused(com.*****.A)
onActivityCreated(com.*****.B)
onActivityStarted(com.*****.B)
onActivityResumed(com.*****.B)
onActivityStopped(com.*****.B)        ??
onActivityDestroyed(com.*****.B)      ??
onActivityStopped(com.*****.A)
```

What do I forget?

EDIT:

My manifest is:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.*****.A"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.*****.B"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" //Try just now with this line, should I keep it?
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and you already have an existing instance of the target `Activity` in the stack, the default behaviour is to clear (finish) all activities in the stack from the topmost `Activity` **back to and including** the target `Activity`, then create a new instance of the target `Activity`. In this case, the new `Intent` will be delivered to `onCreate()` of the new instance.

If you don't want the target `Activity` to be recreated, you need to combine `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, or you need to declare your target `Activity` with `launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest. In this case, the new`Intent`will be delivered to`onNewIntent()` of the existing instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `onNewIntent` is never called for activity **B**. In my notification, I launch activity **A** with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, and in activity **A**, int launch activity **B** with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` (I added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest for activity **B** too), and it don't work, `onNewIntent()` is never called for **B**

Comment: `ActivityB` doesn't exist in the stack when you launch it from `ActivityA`, so Android creates a new instance of `ActivityB`. It won't call `onNewIntent()` in this case.

Comment: Why do you launch `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` using these flags? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Okay I understand. Thing is, I want to launch `Activity B` on click on my notification, but I want to come back to `Activity A` when I quit `Activity B`. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: In other words, how can my notification launch `Activity B`, and `onBackPress` in `Activity B` creates/reuses `Activity A`?

Comment: Ok thanks to your answer I fix my case : my notification launch `Activity B` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, and when I do `onBackPress` on `Activity B`, I start `Activity A` if it doesn't exist. I remove `launchMode="singleTop"` from my Manifest.